# Push batch script to AD clients

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2003, batch

Is it possible to force Active directory clients to run a specific batch script now (without having to restart their computer) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the thing you want to do doesn't require a restart, sure.

Check this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851779.aspx It's an instruction how to set up an immedaite task via AD (only for windows server 2008 and newer, not server 2003 though - you'll need to update ;-) - many things that make your life a LOT easier you cannot get on Win Serv 2003)

Open the Group Policy Management Console. Right-click the Group Policy object (GPO) that should contain the new preference item, and then click Edit .

change to `Computer(or)User configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings` and expand it.

Right-click the Scheduled Tasks node, point to New, select Immediate Task (At least Windows 7) if you're running Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8, or select Immediate Task (Windows Vista and later) if you're running Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7.

You can configure that like a normal scheduled task now.

If that doesn't work (and it won't since you got 2003), you'll need to take another perspective at this case. Maybe `psexec` will fit your needs https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx

With `psexec` you can run Batch commands over your whole network from your workstation. for example `call` a Batch-File

```
psexec @C:\computerlist.txt cmd /c "call C:\mybatch.bat"
```